# FullCalendar (agendaWeek view): titleFormat for weeks overlapping a month

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a question concerning the FullCalendar from Adam Shaw:

My titleFormat for the agendaWeek-View currently is formatted like this:

```
"20 — 26 October 2013"
```

When I go to the next week, it is an overlapping one as part of the week is in October and the rest is in November, resulting in:

```
"27 — 2 November 2013"
```

This is not what I need. The correct way of displaying this week title would be something like this:

```
"27 October — 2 November 2013"
```

Is there a way of accomplishing that?

This is my current titleFormat in fullcalendar:

```
titleFormat: {
   month: 'MMMM yyyy',
   week: "d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;' d MMMM yyyy}",
   day: 'dddd, d.MM.yyyy'
}
```

**EDIT:**

I hadn´t thought of something pretty obvious. Changing the titleFormat option to

```
titleFormat: {
   month: 'MMMM yyyy',
   week: "d MMMM[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;' d MMMM yyyy}",
   day: 'dddd, d.MM.yyyy'
}
```

results in

```
"27 Oktober — 2 November 2013"
```

which is correct. On the other hand I don´t want the month for the start date to be displayed in the non-overlapping weeks - is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
week:  "d [MMM]{ '&#8211;' d MMM}",
```

(add [yyyy] or yyyy if you want)

Answer (score 1):

To optionally display the month, only if it's different, you should be able to put it in square brackets, like so: `[MMMM]`

So your full title format would be:

```
 titleFormat: {
    month: 'MMMM yyyy',
    week: "d MMMM[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;' d [MMMM ]yyyy}",
   day: 'dddd, d.MM.yyyy'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The tip with the brackets did the trick. Just needed them in a different position.